Adding Census Tract to a dataframe based on Latitude and Longitude
I have a large dataset, with two of the following columns:
Latitude      Longitude

39.18207      -76.53715          
39.18207      -76.53715
39.17810      -76.52680
39.17810      -76.52680
39.17810      -76.52680
39.17810      -76.52680
39.44284      -76.22176
39.44284      -76.22176
39.44284      -76.22176
39.44284      -76.22176
39.44284      -76.22176


I want to add a third column called "Tract" with the census tract ID that the corresponding latitude and longitude are in. Essentially, I want to left_join census tracts into my dataframe based on Latitude and Longitude.
All datapoints are in the state of Maryland -- there are multiple rows of data for each latitude and longitude point.
I have tried using tidycensus data, but I don't know how to merge on geometry (the tidycensus data geometry is in "MULTIPOLYGON", but when I convert my data is in "POINT"
library(sf)

MD <- tidycensus::get_acs(state = "MD", geography = "tract",
              variables = "B19013_001", geometry = TRUE)

sf::st_set_crs(MD, 4326)
datsf <- sf::st_as_sf(EIA_Data, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = 4326L)




Sounds like you want a point-in-polygon spatial join. Try joined_df <- sf::st_join(datsf, MD). You can also read more from the author of the tidycensus package here

What you are trying to achieve is called a spatial join. Functions like sf::st_intersection() or st_join() are useful for this purpose. In your case, st_join() is much faster and better as you are only interested in one-to-one, point-to-polygon relationships.
One issue you had with your code is that you needed to use st_transform() to project your MD object to the same CRS as datsf. If you try to do that with st_set_crs(), all it does is treat the coordinate values literally. This is why it throws a warning if you do so.
If you use st_transform(), it will throw a warning as the CRS of your data are not planar. You can safely ignore this waring in this instance. This is another advantage of using st_join(), as it can handle both geographic and projected CRS.
Here's a step-by-step approach to achieve your desired outcome:
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

EIA_Data <- read.table(text = "Latitude      Longitude
39.18207      -76.53715
39.18207      -76.53715
39.17810      -76.52680
39.17810      -76.52680
39.17810      -76.52680
39.17810      -76.52680
39.44284      -76.22176
39.44284      -76.22176
39.44284      -76.22176
39.44284      -76.22176
39.44284      -76.22176", header = TRUE)

# Add unique id for illustrative purposes
EIA_Data <- mutate(EIA_Data, id = 1:n())

# Create sf points object from EIA_Data
datsf <- st_as_sf(EIA_Data, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = 4326)

MD <- tidycensus::get_acs(state = "MD", geography = "tract",
                          variables = "B19013_001", geometry = TRUE)

# Project MD to WGS84/EPSG:4326
MD <- st_transform(MD, 4326)

# Spatially join data and subset columns
datsf <- datsf %>%
  st_join(., MD) %>%
  select(id, NAME)

datsf
# Simple feature collection with 11 features and 2 fields
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -76.53715 ymin: 39.1781 xmax: -76.22176 ymax: 39.44284
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# First 10 features:
#    id                                                NAME                   geometry
# 1   1 Census Tract 7301.02; Anne Arundel County; Maryland POINT (-76.53715 39.18207)
# 2   2 Census Tract 7301.02; Anne Arundel County; Maryland POINT (-76.53715 39.18207)
# 3   3 Census Tract 7301.02; Anne Arundel County; Maryland POINT (-76.5268 39.1781)
# 4   4 Census Tract 7301.02; Anne Arundel County; Maryland POINT (-76.5268 39.1781)
# 5   5 Census Tract 7301.02; Anne Arundel County; Maryland POINT (-76.5268 39.1781)
# 6   6 Census Tract 7301.02; Anne Arundel County; Maryland POINT (-76.5268 39.1781)
# 7   7         Census Tract 3024; Harford County; Maryland POINT (-76.22176 39.44284)
# 8   8         Census Tract 3024; Harford County; Maryland POINT (-76.22176 39.44284)
# 9   9         Census Tract 3024; Harford County; Maryland POINT (-76.22176 39.44284)
# 10 10         Census Tract 3024; Harford County; Maryland POINT (-76.22176 39.44284)

# Return result as df
EIA_Data <- datsf %>%
  mutate(Latitude = st_coordinates(.)[,2],
         Longitude = st_coordinates(.)[,1]) %>%
  st_drop_geometry() %>%
  select(-c(id))

EIA_Data
#                                                   NAME Latitude Longitude
# 1  Census Tract 7301.02; Anne Arundel County; Maryland 39.18207 -76.53715
# 2  Census Tract 7301.02; Anne Arundel County; Maryland 39.18207 -76.53715
# 3  Census Tract 7301.02; Anne Arundel County; Maryland 39.17810 -76.52680
# 4  Census Tract 7301.02; Anne Arundel County; Maryland 39.17810 -76.52680
# 5  Census Tract 7301.02; Anne Arundel County; Maryland 39.17810 -76.52680
# 6  Census Tract 7301.02; Anne Arundel County; Maryland 39.17810 -76.52680
# 7          Census Tract 3024; Harford County; Maryland 39.44284 -76.22176
# 8          Census Tract 3024; Harford County; Maryland 39.44284 -76.22176
# 9          Census Tract 3024; Harford County; Maryland 39.44284 -76.22176
# 10         Census Tract 3024; Harford County; Maryland 39.44284 -76.22176
# 11         Census Tract 3024; Harford County; Maryland 39.44284 -76.22176

A simplified version combining the above code:
# Recreate datsf (use previously projected MD object)
EIA_Data <- read.table(text = "Latitude      Longitude
39.18207      -76.53715
39.18207      -76.53715
39.17810      -76.52680
39.17810      -76.52680
39.17810      -76.52680
39.17810      -76.52680
39.44284      -76.22176
39.44284      -76.22176
39.44284      -76.22176
39.44284      -76.22176
39.44284      -76.22176", header = TRUE)

datsf <- st_as_sf(EIA_Data, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = 4326)

EIA_Data <- st_join(datsf, MD) %>%
  mutate(Latitude = st_coordinates(.)[,2],
         Longitude = st_coordinates(.)[,1]) %>%
  st_drop_geometry() %>%
  select(c(NAME, Latitude, Longitude))

